# Tomcat scaled application can not connect MySQL database

Tags: mysql, tomcat7, scale, openshift

I created my scaled application on Openshift server with following command:

`rhc app create MyApp jbossews-2.0 -s`

Then add Mysql:

`rhc cartridge add mysql-5.5 -a MyApp`

My application using Struts2, Spring & Hibernate. I configured the datasource as follow:
`<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/MysqlDS"/>
 </bean>`

The JNDI "MysqlDS" is defined in .openshift\config\context.xml with the connection url:
`url="jdbc:mysql://5344d4de4382ec43c9000090-myapp.rhcloud.com:37941/mydb"`

The problem is my scale app can not establish the connection to Mysql with an error:
 `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect
3 times. Giving up.)`

I'm sure the username & password to access the database is correct. It seem MySQL on Openshift server doesn't open its port. When I tried to use an external database on freemysqlhosting.net (with open host & port) the application run well. But I just want to use MySQL db on Openshift. Anyone who have experience on this please give me some suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you restarted your application after adding the mysql cartridge, sometimes the environment variables don't show up correctly until you restart.  Also try to ssh to your gear and see if you can use the "mysql" command to connect to your mysql database directly.

Comment: I restarted my application, the connection information which are taken from environment variables still the same. And I'm able to ssh to my gear & can connect mysql & query data directly. I really don't know why the issue happens. Compare to external database, the only different is that db on freemysqlhosting.net open to use port 3306, but openshift use port 37941 which is called MYSQL_DB_PROXY_PORT. It seem my application get stuck with the proxy. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you left the .openshift/config/context.xml unchanged, the JNDI name fore the MySQL datasource is actually jdbc/MySQLDS and not jdbc/MysqlDS.

This was changed some time ago.

The documentation here http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_cartridge_guide.html#tomcat-cartridge-integrations is unfortunately not correct.